# CardStackView's swipe function not working in Android fragment

Tags: android

I am using CardStackView in Android: https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView

In activity, swipe action works well, but in fragment, I cannot use swipe fucntion.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Please show more code. what you have done. what you have tried.

Comment: @jin-pinger can you explain how did you created the layoutmanager for fragment? i am get ting Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class <unknown> error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like followings?

```
    cardStackView.setSwipeEnabled(true);
```

I think if you set swipeenabled as true, it will works

Comment: Great answer! your answer works correctly! why swipeenable is false in fragment?

Comment: I dont understand correctly, but in my opinion, it happens because layout has complicated constructure.

Comment: Is there any way to swipe when I click button?

Comment: If you made button, and set function like swipleft, swiperight, swipetop to button onclick function, you can implement those functions.

Comment: Great answer. THank you for your help

Comment: My pleasure! Your question is not normal question but this was my experience

Comment: Do you know another library of swipe view?

Comment: Sorry, NO. i will comment here if I find new one

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue:

manager.setSwipeableMethod(SwipeableMethod.AutomaticAndManual);

Fixed it for me.